# Django query function not properly filtering for user type

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter all my users and select ones that have `user is teacher = True` and `user has instrument1 ='Cello'`. My function is displaying all the users, instead of just the teachers, that have `user has instrument1 ='Cello'`. I am wondering how to properly write my function so that it selects teachers as well. If users are a teacher they are saved in my database with a `user.teacher=1`, else `user.teacher=0`.

views.py

```
def teacher_list(request):
    data = User.objects.filter(Q(teacher=True) and Q(instrument1='Cello'))
    form = TeacherProfileForm()
    context = {'form' : form, 'data' : data}
    return render(request, 'view/teacher_list.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<div class="desktop">
    {% for user in data %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 left">
            <img src="{{ user.avatar.url }}" height="170" width="170">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mid">
            <h3>{{ user.first_name|capfirst }} {{ user.last_name|capfirst }}</h3>
            <h5>{% if user.instrument1 != "" %}{{ user.instrument1|capfirst }}{% endif %}{% if user.instrument2 != ""%}, {{ user.instrument2|capfirst }}{% endif %}{% if user.instrument3 != "" %}, {{user.instrument3|capfirst }}{% endif %}{% if user.instrument4 != "" %}, {{ user.instrument4|capfirst}}{% endif %}{% if user.instrument5 != "" %}, {{ user.instrument5|capfirst }}{% endif %}</h5>
            <p>{{ user.bio|capfirst }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 right">
            <br />
            <x-star-rating value="5" number="5" id="rating"></x-star-rating>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="{% url 'view:profile' user.id %}">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn blue_button">Book Lesson</button>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <hr />
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you please add your User model defination and also 1 and true is not same.

Comment: Show us your models please

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** Do not use the `and` operator to combine `Q` objects. In Python, the `and` operator returns one of the operands, depending on the truthiness of the first one. Use `&`, or, like here, you can simplify the expression.

**Background**: Do *not* use `and` to combine two `Q` objects. `and` in Python is a function that inspects the truthiness of the first operand and if that one is `False` then returns the first one, otherwise it returns the second operand. Here this thus means that:

```
>>> Q(teacher=True) and Q(instrument1='Cello')
<Q: (AND: ('instrument1', 'Cello'))>
```

whereas:

```
>>> Q(teacher=True) & Q(instrument1='Cello')
<Q: (AND: ('teacher', True), ('instrument1', 'Cello'))>
```

Indeed, since `Q` objects with a condition have truthiness `True`, the `Q(teacher=True) and Q(instrument1='Cello')` expression will retrurn the *second* operand, so `Q(instrument1='Cello')`

In fact you do not need `Q` objects in the first place, you can query like:

```
def teacher_list(request):
    data = User.objects.filter(teacher=True, instrument1='Cello')
    form = TeacherProfileForm()
    context = {'form' : form, 'data' : data}
    return render(request, 'view/teacher_list.html', context)
```